# How to link menu item with a page?

Tags: html, web, hyperlink, href

This is a  part from my HTML5 code:

```
<nav>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">Home</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">Basic information</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">Technical parameters</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
        </div>
</nav>
```

Now I realized, that when I open my browser and I click in the menu for example on the home button nothing happens. How can I link the home button with my home.html document?

Comment: [`<a>`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One alternative is to surround the buttons with a form-tag, like this:`<form action="/something.html">`. The other alternative is to use a link-tag `<a href="" class=""></a>`, which U style as a button, and use the same classes for. You can read more here as well [Link with button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-to-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link)

Answer (score 0):

To do this using a `button` element, you would need to involve some Javascript.

The home button code should look something like this:

```
<button class="dropbtn" onclick="location.href='home.html';">Home</button>
```

Alternatively, you can just use a hyperlink tag `a` along with CSS:

```
<a class="dropbtn" href="home.html">Home</a>
```

This is easier to work with when it comes to styling and being able to just out of the box HTML functionality.